# Give asp:hyperlink in a repeater a url from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay so imagine next situation:
I have a .ascx file with a repeater and in this repeater there is a asp:hyperlink.
Is it possible to set the url of this hyperlink from the code behind?

In the end the link will always point towards the same url but it needs to be repeated x-times.

test code ascx:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="container">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypUrl" runat="server" Text="Dit is een test link">   </asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Normally in the code behind I would do something like:

```
hypUrl.NavigateUrl = Url;
```

But because the hyperlink is in a repeater it doesnt seem to find the ID.
Anyone knows what the best way is to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KrishnrajRana There's no need to comment to say "check my answer". The person that asked the question will be automatically notified when you post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your `repeater_ItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        // Find the hyperlink
        HyperLink hypUrl = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hypUrl");

        // Set the property
        hypUrl.NavigateUrl = "foo";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In repeater's **ItemDataBound event**. Do it like this

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
            HyperLink hypLink = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hypUrl");
            hypLink.NavigateUrl = "http//www.stackoverflow.com";
    }
}
```